# Laravel unsupported get method

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with getting some info from database in Laravel. I'm trying to use where method and specify id that I need to but I always have error like

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

Here is the code
Controller

```
public function select_category($category_id){
        $products = Products::where('category_id', $category_id)->get();

        return $products;
    }
```

Api

```
Route::get('products/{category_id}', 'ProductsController@select_category');
```

When I delete `$category_id` and where, only have like `Products::all();` works fine, but need to specify where to search.

Link how I specify the $category_id is `http://localhost:8000/api/products/?category_id=16`

Comment: Can you post here other routes that are starts with "products"?

Comment: I think your link is a problem. Try ```http://localhost:8000/api/products/16``` or if you want to specify it is specific category product then create a route like ```Route::get('products/categories/{category_id}', 'ProductsController@select_category');``` and call it with ```http://localhost:8000/api/products/categories/16```

Answer (score 0):

The log indicate that there is a route error, it has nothing to do with your Eloquent model

Check if you have another route conflicting with that one

---

Edit : After seeing your URL, you should use "http://localhost:8000/api/products/16" rather than "http://localhost:8000/api/products/?category_id=16"

The second one try to access your post route "Route::post('products'..." because, to Laravel, everything after the "?" is a parameter and isn't used in route detection

Comment: This is all routes that I have
Route::get('products/{id}', 'ProductsController@show');
Route::post('products', 'ProductsController@store');
Route::put('products/{id}', 'ProductsController@update');
Route::delete('products/{id}', 'ProductsController@delete');

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your routes file, below the definition of this route you don't have similar endpoint set for a post method. So you most probably have:

```
Route::post('products/something', 'ProductsController@store');
```

this will override the previously defined one.

To prevent this, you can modify your current route to this:

```
Route::get('products/{category_id}', 'ProductsController@select_category')->where('category_id', '[0-9]+');
```

Comment: I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

change your URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/products/16
```

also change in a view file:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('products/'. $yourchategoryid ) }}">product</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
 public function select_category(Request $request, $category_id){
        $products = Products::where('category_id', $category_id)->get();

        return $products;
    }
```

if url is

```
http://localhost:8000/api/products/16
```

and if url is

```
http://localhost:8000/api/products/?category_id=16
```

function should be

```
public function select_category(Request $request){
            $products = Products::where('category_id', $request->input('category_id'))->get();

        return $products;
    }
```

first parameter of the function should be `Request` class instance